# RxJava Fetch from Api if cache expired

Tags: android, realm, retrofit2, rx-java2

I need to query data from Api then save it to Realm object. I need to get the data(observable) to the Presenter from the realm object unless 5 minutes from the last Api query elapsed, in other case I need to fetch from Api again. I`m new to RxJava. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a class hosting a `ReplaySubject` and some update logic:

```
class TimedCache<T> {
    final Subject<T> cache = 
        ReplaySubject.createWithTime(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).toSerialized();

    final Single<T> valueProvider;

    TimedCache(Single<T> valueProvider) {
        this.valueProvider = valueProvider;
    }

    public Observable<T> valueObservable() {
        return cache.take(1)
           .switchIfEmpty(
               valueProvider
               .doOnSuccess(v -> {
                   cache.onNext(v);
                   // update realm here
               })
               .toObservable()
           );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What is the best way to connect to Api? Because if just pass a single from Api request, i anyway need to fetch every time

Comment: What is your source? Retrofit let's you define an API endpoint with `Single` so do other technologies supporting RxJava.

Comment: I use retrofit, I mean how do I know when to fetch the API?

Comment: If the cache is empty or gets old (thus empty), it will start fetching the data from that `Single`. Just start observing the `valueObservable`.

Comment: Im getting "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." but I`m subscribing on the IO thread

Comment: You have to `subscribeOn` the value provider: `new TimedCache<>(someAPI.call().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))`.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up two different observables:

1.) for observing the Realm data:

```
realm.where(MyData.class)
     .findAllAsync()
     .asFlowable()
     .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
     .subscribe(...);
```

2.) for fetching the data every 5 minutes

```
Observable.interval(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .switchMap((ignored) -> {
              return apiService.getData();
          })
          .subscribe((data) -> {
              try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                  realm.executeTransaction((r) -> {
                      r.insertOrUpdate(data);
                  }); 
              }
          });
```

---

**EDIT:** then just call a method like

```
flowable = realm.where(MyData.class)
     .findAllAsync()
     .asFlowable()
     .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
     .subscribe(...);

if(cache.isOlderThanFiveMinutes()) {
    startRefreshTaskOnBackgroundThread();
}
```

Comment: in this case, it is not network efficient because the fetching starting just then user clicks the button.